# How would you create a tree from a list and display it in Excel or PowerBI?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

I have a list that I don't maintain, and I want to reorganize it and display it in some visual fashion, like a tree. (In my mind, I'm imagining the old tree function in DOS.)
Imagine a family tree that is listed as following:

-ID     Name    ParentID

1. ```
   Adam.   0
   ```
2. ```
   Eve.    0
   ```
3. ```
   Caine.  1
   ```
4. ```
   Abel.   1
   ```
5. ```
   Jon.    3
   ```
6. ```
   Mike.   3
   ```
7. ```
   Richard 5
   ```

I think I want it to display something like:

- Adam

  - Caine

    - Jon

      - Richard
    - Mike
  - Abel
- Eve

I am extremely good in Excel and Power Apps. I'm just really drawing a blank on how to manipulate this with a query or anything, or even how to display it.
The total list has about 12 tiers and 10k objects.
I want to avoid VBA and would prefer to use PowerBI where you choose a top tier and get drop downs to drill all the way down.
I'm probably missing something stupid obvious, and I'm just having, what I call, a brain fart or writers block.
I spent an hour writing a formula to determine what level each object exists, so Adam would be tier 1, Richard would be tier 4, in the example above. I don't know if that helps me in any way.
(And yes, I'm writing this on my phone. Work blocks this site.)

Comment: If you can access add-ins, then check out the FREE Microsoft Visio Data Visualizer. It has a built in org chart. A pivot table might be another option, but I think you need to build out all the tiers in different columns (which it sounds like you can do).

Comment: Are you looking for the Group feaure?